# node.js express res.send in callback issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

I have a node.js script which dose two things :

1. Start a http server that listen to POST request from browser.
2. Start a socket connect to a java server

When a request come from the browser I will send some data to the java server using socket and then return the data from java server to the browser in http response.

It works fine for the first request but in the second request I will get the error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Here is the node.js script:

```
var client = new net.Socket();
var clientConnected = false;

app.options('*', cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var data = new Buffer('');
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        // read buffer data from the browser in the POST request
        data = Buffer.concat([data, chunk]);
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        req.rawBody = data;
        next();
    });
});

app.post('/xxxxxx', function(req, res) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (!clientConnected) {
        // if the socket is not connected, create it
        client.connect(G_PORT, G_ADDRESS, function() {
            clientConnected = true;
        });

        client.on('close', function() {
            clientConnected = false;
        });

        client.on('data',function(data) {
            // get result from the java server through socket
            res.send(data);
        });

        client.on('error', function(error){
            clientConnected = false;
        });
        res.send();
    }
    else {
        // the socket is created, just send the data to socket
        client.write(req.rawBody);
    }
});
```

The error is pointed to the line :

```
res.send(data);
```

in

```
client.on('data',function(data)
```

I am quite new to express and hope someone can give me some advice, thanks :)

UPDATE:

I tried to close the socket every time I finish one request and in this case everything works fine:

```
if (true) {
    var client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(G_PORT, G_ADDRESS, function() {
        client.write(data);
    });
    client.on('close', function(){
    });

    client.on('data',function(data){
        res.send(decodeData);
        client.destroy();
    });

    client.on('error', function(error){
    });
}
```

It seem the issue has something to do with my global socket instance ???

Answer (score 2):

The error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." come when you called res.send when one is already called.

On your post request you have 2 res.send

```
    client.on('data',function(data) {
        // get result from the java server through socket
        res.send(data);
    });

    client.on('error', function(error){
        clientConnected = false;
    });
    res.send();
```

When the client is on 'data' you send also in res.send and that's make error. You need for each request only one res.send

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried to comment out the second .send function and I am still having the same error.

Comment: BTW, the second .send function will only be triggered the first time a post request come. And in the first request I will not send any data to the server (create socket only)  so the .send function in callback will not be triggered.

Comment: It's normal. When your client is on 'data' you res.send, and default size of data max is 8192. So if you have a message of 10000 you will be twice on client.on('data', -> and you will call twice res.send

Comment: What do you want to realize with your post request ?

Comment: I want to send the data from browser to the server using socket and then wait for the result from the server and finally send the result back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should Try that.

```
var client = new net.Socket();
var clientConnected = false;

app.options('*', cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var data = new Buffer('');
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        // read buffer data from the browser in the POST request
        data = Buffer.concat([data, chunk]);
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        req.rawBody = data;
        next();
    });
});

app.post('/xxxxxx', function(req, res) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (!clientConnected) {
        // if the socket is not connected, create it
        var buffer = '';
        client.connect(G_PORT, G_ADDRESS, function() {
            clientConnected = true;
        });

        client.on('close', function() {
            clientConnected = false;
        });

        client.on('data',function(data) {
            buffer += data;
        });

        client.on('error', function(error){
            clientConnected = false;
        });
        client.on('end', function() {
            res.send(buffer);
        });
    } else {
        // the socket is created, just send the data to socket
        client.write(req.rawBody);
        res.send(req.rawBody);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this solution and this time the error is gone... but the 'end' callback is never triggered so my browser can not get any data back...

Comment: try on the close listener and tell me ;)

Comment: You mean try to add the res.send(buffer); in the close callback?  I tried that but the close callback is never triggered since my socket will keep alive after connected to the server ......